# Simplify keep as single fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to simplify: $\frac {15a+5}{10a}$ . I believe it would be $\frac{3a+1}{2a}$ ? We cant cancel the a since we are performing addition I believe? Sorry for the fundamental question I am doing calculus and forgot the simplicities.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "simplify."  Yes, the simplification you propose is one among many that can be done.  You might also choose to separate the fraction into two as $\frac{15a+5}{10a}=\frac{5(3a+1)}{5(2a)}=\frac{3a+1}{2a}=\frac{3a}{2a}+\frac{1}{2a}=\frac{5}{2}+\frac{1}{2a}$ if you so choose.

Comment: You have the right idea, except $\frac {15}{5} = 3$

Comment: @DougM thanks for that catch. Typo!

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks so its all the same answer just different form?

Comment: Yes, and in most situations and in particular for personal use, the form you end up with is your own personal preference.  Some will make certain properties more obvious, such as the $\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2a}$ form shows that if $a$ is a variable, the graph has a clear horizontal asymptote at $\frac{3}{2}$ which might not be as immediately visible otherwise to an untrained eye.  (*I missed my chance to fix my edit above, its a $\frac{3}{2}$ not a $\frac{5}{2}$ whoops*).

Comment: If it is for the benefit of someone else and they ask you to "simplify" an expression, that is unfortunately ambiguous.  In some cases, there is a clear "nice" simplification, such as how $\binom{n}{0}-\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}-\binom{n}{3}+\dots\pm\binom{n}{n}=0$, but in situations like this whether one form is "more" or "less" simplified than another is quite subjective.  Usually they mean to have you perform the most obvious simplifications which generally reduce coefficients, the number of terms, or make certain properties more visible (*such as in factoring to make roots visible*)

Comment: @JMoravitz This question seems to be resolved, so could you please convert one or more of your helpful comments into an answer?